# Access button from another ViewController in iOS?

Tags: ios, uisegmentedcontrol, viewcontroller

I have two ViewControllers. One has a button, and the other ViewController has a segmented control to turn the button on or off. My question is: how can I access the button from ViewController 1 to be turned off in ViewController 2? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The most simple way would be declare the button as a property in header file and access directly from other file.However it's ugly and increase code coupling. You can use make one controller as other one's delegate and notify the delegate when the state of segment control changed.

Answer (score 2):

or else you can use notification

In View Controller 1 :

```
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(togglebutton) name:@"togglebutton" object:nil];
```

and method

```
 -(void)togglebutton{
    //turn button on/off
}
```

In ViewController 2:

```
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:@"togglebutton" object:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of declaring that button as a property in header file

write a method in the viewcontroller1 which has button
and in that method turn the button on/off

Now you can call this method from other viewcontroller2 which has a segmented control to turn the button on or off.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not the best solution but my best guess is your segmented control is a switch of some sort for your app.

In that case, in your **ViewController2**, when you change the value of your segmented control, you can write it to `NSUserDefaults` like so:

```
-(void)segmentedControlChanged:(id)sender
{
    UISegmentedControl *ctrl = (UISegmentedControl *)sender;

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:ctrl.selectedSegmentIndex] forKey:@"selectedIndex"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

Then in your **ViewController1**'s `viewDidAppear` method, you check for the value of **selectedIndex** like so:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSNumber *selectedIndex = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"selectedIndex"];

    if(selectedIndex != nil)
    {
        if([selectedIndex intValue] == 0)
        {
            NSLog(@"do action 1");
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"else do action 2");
        }
    }
}
```

Would that suffice for your intentions?